# ngx-translate how to test components

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, internationalization, ngx-translate

I've got an application which uses this library. How do I test components with it? I DO NOT WANT TO TEST THE LIBRARY. I just need to start tests of my component without multiple errors about TranslateModule then TranslateService then TranslateStore ... until I get an error when compiling.

Is there an easy way to just run my tests with this dependency?

Once more, I don't want to test this library (check whether the string is being translated) I need to run tests on components which rely on this library.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need the keys to be translated you can import the `TranslateModule` in your test like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      ...
    ],
    imports: [
      TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    providers: [
      ...
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

It will only show the translation keys

Comment: Works fine in angular 8 + ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1, thanks

Comment: Works fine with angular 11

Comment: Works also fine with angular 15

Answer (score 24):

For me the ngx-translate-testing worked well
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-testing

first

```
import { TranslateTestingModule } from 'ngx-translate-testing';
```

then

```
  imports: [
    ...
    TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations({ en: require('src/assets/i18n/en.json'), de: require('src/assets/i18n/de.json') })
  ],
```

then test

```
  it('should render german title', inject([TranslateService], (translateService: TranslateService) => {
    translateService.setDefaultLang('de');
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.title').textContent).toContain('GERMANTITLE');
  }));
```

Comment: TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-translate-testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

Answer (score 19):

(Tested with Angular 8.1.0 and ngx-translate 11.0.1)

**A)** If you use the **translate pipe** in your component, create a `TranslateMockPipe` and add it to the `declarations` array of your spec (as proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/635#issuecomment-322982789)).

*translate-mock.pipe.ts*

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: "translate"
})
export class TranslateMockPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public name: string = "translate";

  public transform(query: string, ...args: any[]): any {
    return query;
  }
}
```

*your-component.spec.ts*

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ YourComponent, TranslateMockPipe ],
      imports: [
        ...
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

In one case for some reason I also had to do step B).

**B)** If you use the **translate service directly** in your component, e.g. `this.translate.get('foo.bar')`, you'll need to import the `TranslateModule` and use the ngx-translate `TranslateFakeLoader` as a `loader` for it.

*your-component.spec.ts*

```
import {TranslateFakeLoader, TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ YourComponent ], // you may add TranslateMockPipe from step 1 here, too
      imports: [
        ...
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: TranslateFakeLoader
          }
        })
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

This way, you can use the ngx-translate built-in Stub instead of creating your own as proposed in [issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/636)  (it didn't work for me either).

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is to setup all my translation related configuration in a separate `TranslationModule` that I import to a `SharedModule`.

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: IfYouHaveACustomFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })],
  exports: [TranslateModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class TranslationModule {

}
```

This can then be exported to all components that import the `SharedModule`,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [TranslationModule, SomeOtherModule],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And in your spec-file you simply import the `SharedModule` in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` like

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        SharedModule,
...
```

And tests for components that use the translation service or pipe should run fine!

Comment: I like this idea, but it doesn't work for me. The translate-pipe does no longer translate anything when I remove the  TranslateModule.forRoot({...}) stuff from my app.module.ts where I had it before. Just importing my shared-module does not see to be enough to make it work.

Comment: And in the tests I get errors like `NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[TranslatePipe -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TranslatePipe -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!`